# New install of Docker Toolbox yields "AppleEvent timed out." error

Tags: macos, docker

I installed the new version of Docker toolbox on a fresh machine. The install stated it was a success, yet when I start up the Docker Quickstart Terminal app, I get an odd error.

```
AppleEvent timed out.
Terminal got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)
```

Googling this error proved to be fruitless.

1. I uninstalled and reinstalled
2. I restarted
3. I uninstalled, restarted, changed networks, and so on.

Has anyone else had these errors?

OSX YOSEMITE

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, I'm hitting the same issue. Very frustrating.

Comment: Yea. I wish I could close this issue. but seems that i some how solved it. I totally uninstalled docker, and xcode, and reinstalled from scratch. Hole that helps.